# How can I manage source code in TFVC with two developers?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

Until now i only worked on projects by myself, but a new dev got assigned to my project and im trying to figure out how we best work together regarding source control.

I got 2 branches, MainBranch thats mine, and JuniorBranch thats the branch of my colleague.
The general workflow that i build up after playing around with TFS some

1. Create a new branch from main
2. We both do our work and check in changes into our own branches
3. I get the newest version of JuniorBranch and review her changes
4. I go into source control explorer and merge the JuniorBranch into my MainBranch

Here is where i got confused. The changes that i merged show up on my laptop in MainBranch. Completely automatically, without me having to click get latest version or getting any popup or anything!

BUT if i check the "Server version", the one on our TFS website, the changes arent there yet, they only get commited once i check in again.

Especially the part where the changes "just show up" on my local version has me confused. How can this even happen? How do i prevent merging some change that she and i forgot about into MainBranch? How is everyone (with permission i guess) allowed to just *silently* merge changes into my MainBranch? How do they just show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An advantage of using Team Foundation version control to manage your files is that **several people can work concurrently on a file**.

One drawback is that sometimes you must resolve conflicts before you can get, check in, unshelve, merge, or roll back your files. Although it can be frustrating to encounter conflicts, our TFS system provides information and tools to help you understand and resolve conflicts.

Just as Daniel pointed out, when you **merge files**, these files are not immediately merge to target branch. There are **listed as pending changes first**. Unless you checked in your pending changes. Otherwise, target branch will not be updated.

Besides, if others (workflow) check in changes during your merge process, definitely contain some conflicts you need to resolve.

When you say the local version or server version. You must first check if you are using [sever workspace or local workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops). There are some difference.

Not sure if totally get your point, if you still have concern, suggest you include some screenshots to make it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Running the merge process **starts** a merge. The merge doesn't get committed until **you** commit it. This gives you a chance to review the changes and resolve conflicts.

They didn't "just show up". You made them show up by virtue of starting a merge.

Comment: i think im missing something about how server and local version work in TFS. What i would think is happening: I got a local version on my laptop, there is a server versionin TFS. If someone merges or checks in changes from somewhere else, they should show up on the server, but not on my local version until i hit "get latest version". But kinda the exact opposite is happening... so server/local version cant be working how i think they do.

Comment: What you described is correct when **someone else** merges. When you merge, it works the way I described. Merging is a multi-step process that takes place on the machine of whoever initiates the merge.